# ¿Como hacer uso de exclude para usar en un formulario con django?

Tags: python, django

Mi duda en si es poder hacer que los campos que esten con exclude puedan ser llenados a traves de un formulario pero aun no se como poder mostrar estos mismos datos

**codigo de models.py**

```
 class Producto(models.Model):
     nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     caracteristica= models.CharField(max_length=10)
     codigo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     estado = models.BooleanField(default=True)
     observacion = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=True)
```

**codigo del form.py**

```
 class ProductoForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Proveedor
         exclude = ['estado' , 'observacion']
```

**codigo del views.py**

```
def crear_producto(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductoForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('producto:producto_list')
 else:
     form = venta_form()
 return render(request, 'almacenes/productos_crear.html', {'form': form})
```

**Codigo de los botones donde llamo al formulario.html**

```
  <a href="{% url 'producto:crear_producto' %}" class="btn btn-success" title="Baja Proveedor"> Crear </a>
   <!-- Parte del boton del codigo de los exclude -->
  <a href=" " class="btn btn-primary" title="Dar Obervacion y Estado">Mas ... </a>
```

Comment: No se entiende muy bien tu problema, dinos que espera que suceda exactamente, y qué has intentado hacer para que esto que deseas resulte, y así podremos ayudarte mucho mejor

Comment: pues ya lo puse ahi, osea en mi forms.py tengo lo que es exclude en donde menciono los campos que quiero excluir de ese formulario, hasta ahora me sale que los dato son excluidos cuando habre mi formulario, hasta ahi esta todo bien, y ahora esos datos de exclude no han sido llenados, y ahi es el problema, ahora quiero llenar esos datos excluidos abriendo a travez de otro boton , agregando esos campos excluidos en otro formulario. eso es todo. es ahi donde esta el problema no se como llamar a esos datos excluidos en mi views.py  ni como mostrarlo en un formulario.

Answer (score 0):

Si te estoy entendiendo bien, lo que estás buscando hacer es un formulario multipágina. Para esto no te sirve `exclude`, porque esto está hecho para que esos campos no se tengan en cuenta en el formulario en ningún momento.

Si quieres hacer un formulario multipágina puedes utilizar [form wizard](http://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html) de [django-formtools](http://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), que se basa en la creación de un formulario por cada una de las páginas del wizard.

[Aquí tienes un ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901680/how-to-do-a-multi-step-form-in-django) sencillo de cómo ponerlo en marcha.

Si lo que quieres no es un formulario multipágina, sino más bien dos formularios que hagan distintas cosas, sencillamente crea dos formularios. De esta forma:

```
class ProductCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Producto
        exclude = ['estado' , 'observacion']

class ProductUpdateStateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Producto
        fields = ['estado', 'observacion']
```

Y utilizas cada cual cuando sea necesario.